# aws - IPV6 with EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have EC2 instance that is running on IPV4.
How can i get IPV6?
[image]

I tried with managed EC2 board but i do not have anything related to IPV6:
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-2#ManageIpAddresses:instanceId=i-06228e8aed3dc8931

I also tried to reboot my EC2 instance but nothing.
I checked if i need to upgrade my instance to a better one, but not that.

I have basic plan with t2.micro.

Comment: Do you have the vpc/subnet configured for IPV6?

Answer (score 1):

Ok thank to this tutorial i succeed:
https://4sysops.com/archives/assign-an-ipv6-address-to-an-ec2-instance-dual-stack/

The conclusion is 100% true :

> Now you understand why DevOps is so popular in the cloud. That's lots
> of click-click for such a simple task. On the other hand, I guess it
> wouldn't be a big deal for Amazon to simply add an "Enable IPv6"
> option to the VPC settings, so that instead of 15 steps, just one
> click would do the trick.